# Erro depois de configurar authorization no Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

estou com problema para acessa a aplicação MVC logo depois de fazer a configuração no Web.config para fazer a autenticação com o usuário do windows. O erro ocorre ao habilitar a seguinte linha:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="maquinaLocal\usuario"/>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

E ao executar a aplicação ocorre o seguinte erro:

***Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
Acesso negado. 
  Descrição: Erro ao acessar os recursos necessários para atender esta solicitação. Talvez o servidor não esteja configurado para acessar o URL necessário.***

Lembrando que meu controller Home esta assim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        if (windowsIdentity != null)
            ViewBag.User = windowsIdentity.Name;

        return View();
    }
```

E quando comento a linha do "authorization" do Web.config a aplicação funciona normalmente.

```
<!--<authorization>
  <allow users="maquinaLocal\usuario"/>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>-->
```

O que pode ser isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua configuração está errada. Isto aqui nem funciona:

```
<allow users="maquinaLocal\usuario"/>
```

A configuração abaixo:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Diz que todo usuário não-autenticado deve ter o acesso negado. Os demais podem ter acesso a tudo.

No MVC, para realizar autenticação, usa-se um *Attribute* chamado [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). Cada *Controller* que necessita de autenticação deve ser anotado com ele. Por exemplo:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestesController : Controller
{ ... }
```

Claro que esse atributo tem pouca utilidade se você está usando Active Directory para permitir ou bloquear usuários. Uma das coisas que fiz numa aplicação minha foi reescrever o atributo de autorização verificando ou a estrutura do próprio Active Directory, ou então o banco de dados. Por exemplo:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ActiveDirectoryAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private String[] _permissoes = new String[] { "GrupoDaTI" };
    public ActiveDirectoryUserViewModel ActiveDirectoryInfo;
    private MeuProjetoContext contexto = new MeuProjetoContext();

    public ActiveDirectoryAuthorizeAttribute(params String[] permissoes) 
    {
        _permissoes = _permissoes.Concat(permissoes).ToArray();
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var baseReturn = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        ActiveDirectoryInfo = ActiveDirectoryHelper.GetADUserByLogin(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        var grupos = ActiveDirectoryInfo.Groups.Select(g => g.DisplayName).ToList();

        var permissoesUsuario = false;
        permissoesUsuario = contexto.GrupoUsuario.Where(s => grupos .Contains(s.Grupo.Nome)).Any();

        return permissoesUsuario && baseReturn;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/NaoAutorizado");
    }
}
```

Isto é um exemplo de como pode ser feito. Outra coisa que você pode fazer é armazenar os *Security Identifiers* do Active Directory que podem ter acesso a um determinado ponto da aplicação.

`ActiveDirectoryInfo` e `ActiveDirectoryHelper` [podem ser encontrados nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83103/como-criar-conector-para-active-diretory/83123#83123).